# Submit <button> doesn't work with Materialize CSS, but submit <input> tag works - Solution

Tags: php, html, forms

I initially created an app with a form and a submit button.

```
<input id="submitFileUrlForDownload" type="submit" name="fileurlsubmitted">
```

It worked well until I started using Materialize to style the app. Materialize requires developers to use `button` tag instead of `input type="submit"` for styling reasons.

**But while the submit worked without Materialize, it stopped working, though not a line of PHP code changed.**

What may be the reason? This is how I solved this issue.

Comment: Somehow, having `disabled` in your input tag makes it look like you don't actually want it to work.

Comment: Tom, this does not have anything to do with submission logic. I need "disabled" and I have a JS to handle that.

Comment: I will actually remove the 'disabled' part not to confuse the audience.

Comment: I see, do you mind sharing a bit of that javascript with us? Maybe there is something wrong there that is causing this.

Comment: Tom, I removed disabled attribute to test whether form submission works with <button> (which has no value attribute). And I had the same issue with submission. Removed JS and tested - and again the same thing. The problem is solved, I just posted the solution in case someone else stumbles on this.

Answer (score 1):

Set the type attribute of the button tag to 'submit'. You can make a button submit form data. [See here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp)

```
<button type="submit" name="fileurlsubmitted" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="submitFileUrlForDownload" disabled>Download<i class="material-icons right">file_download</i></button>
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue. This is why I wrote this question. Submit is redundant in this case, since `<button>`'s purpose is to submit things.

Comment: Buttons can be used to reset form data as well. Not just submit.

Comment: Yeah, but again type="submit" does not help in this case, tested this once again now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was that I needed to add `value="any_value"` inside the `button` tag and PHP submission worked again. The value is not used anywhere actually, but it seems it's essential for a form submit button.

So compare the two pieces of code:

1. Will work but will look awfully with Materialize:

`<input id="submitFileUrlForDownload" type="submit" name="fileurlsubmitted">`

2. Will not work with Materialize, using `<button>`

`<button name="fileurlsubmitted" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="submitFileUrlForDownload">Download<i class="material-icons right">file_download</i></button>`

3. Will work with Materialize, using `<button>` and `value`

`<button name="fileurlsubmitted" value="ANY_VALUE_HERE" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="submitFileUrlForDownload">Download<i class="material-icons right">file_download</i></button>`